# Convert string to date in dart

Tags: dart, datetime, type-conversion

How can I convert date string in format 'Jan 12, 2022' to date type in Dart?

I tried DateTime.parse() but it returns error Invalid Date Format.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, int> month = {
      'jan' : DateTime.january,
      'feb': DateTime.february,
      'mar': DateTime.march
      //..... and so on
    };

    String dateString = 'Jan 12, 2022';

    int year = int.parse(dateString.split(' ').last);
    int day = int.parse(dateString.split(' ')[1].replaceAll(',', ''));
    String monthKey = dateString.split(' ').first.toLowerCase();



    DateTime date = DateTime(
      year,
      month[monthKey]!,
      day
);
```